# Pyramid AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy callback never invoked

Tags: python, pyramid

Im trying to implement simple authentication in Pyramid by using AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy. I follow [this - authentication](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/authentication.html) and [this - authorization](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/authorization.html).

**init**.py

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator

from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy
from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy
from .security import groupfinder, Root


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    #config = Configurator(settings=settings)

    # ACL
    config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory=Root)
    authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy('sosecret', callback=groupfinder, hashalg='sha512')
    authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
    config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
    config.set_authorization_policy(authz_policy)

    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    config.include('.models')
    config.include('.routes')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

security.py

```
GROUPS = {'admin': ['group:admin']}
USERS = {'receptionist' : 'receptionist'}

def groupfinder(userid, request):
    print("It's here")
    return ['group:admin']

from pyramid.security import Allow, Everyone

class Root(object):
    def __acl__(self):
        return [(Allow, Everyone, 'view'), (Allow, 'group:admin', 'edit')]

def __init__(self, request):
    pass
```

my view default.py

```
...

@view_config(route_name='login', renderer='../templates/login.jinja2')
def login(request):
    try:
        if not ('user_name' in request.params and 'password' in request.params):
            return {}

        if request.params['user_name'] == '' or request.params['password'] == '':
            raise Exception('Ada inputan yang kosong dari form')

        match_ = request.dbsession.query(TblUser).filter_by(user_name=request.params['user_name'], user_password=request.params['password']).one()
        username = request.params['user_name']

        if match_ is not None:
            headers = remember(request, username)
            request.response.headerlist.extend(headers)
            next_url = request.route_url('search-room')

            return HTTPFound(location=next_url)

    except Exception as e:
        log.exception(str(e))
        return {'code' : 'error', 'message' : str(e) }

...

@view_config(route_name='search-room', renderer='../templates/search-room.jinja2', permission='edit')
def search_room(request):
    try:
        if not ('floor' in request.params):
            return {}

        if request.params['floor'] == '':
            raise Exception('Ada inputan yang kosong dari form')

        query = request.dbsession.query(TblReservation)
        result = query.join(TblRoom, aliased=True).filter_by(room_floor=request.params['floor']).all()

        if result is None or len(result) < 1:
            raise Exception("No row found")

        return {'code' : 'ok', 'message' : '', 'content' : result }

    except Exception as e:
        log.exception(str(e))
        return {'code' : 'error', 'message' : str(e), 'content' : ''}
```

Full code in repo https://github.com/muhakbaryasin/pyramid-simple-acl

I set at least the user need to be authenticated and authorized as 'admin' so it can get 'edit' role and access 'search-room' page.

What I got right now is the login process is done but it wont give the authorization to access 'search-room' and the **groupfinder** is never invoked.

What do I miss? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a diff against the [source in the Pyramid Quick Tutorial](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/master/docs/quick_tutorial/authorization) to find what you missed.

Comment: Ok. I will try it out

Comment: I've solved this issue. It's beause the header that contain the cookie was not preserved. I miss the HTTPFound(location=next_url)  -> HTTPFound(location=next_url, headers=headers)

Comment: @campnew: I have a similar error, can you check this code provide your inputs - https://github.com/PREM1980/authentication/tree/main/spa_authentication   Infact, I have called the remember function.